# Popup disappears

Tags: qt, popup

I have made a popup in QT using a QFrame. This QFrame has two QPushButtons on it, namely a cancel and an OK button. I want the popup to disappear only when one of these buttons is pushed. Unfortunately the popup also disappears when I click next to the popup! Which setting do I use to disable this? So how can I make it stay on top as long as I dont push the OK or cancel button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use QDialog with setModal(true); http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qdialog.html